# react navigation with redux not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I want to change routes from my action js files, so
the navReducer.js which is combined to the root Reducer is

```
const router = RootStack.router;
const initialState = router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.init());

export default navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  return router.getStateForAction(action, state);

}
```

and the mainRoute.js which is connected to the reducer is

```
const SiraRoute = (props) => (
    <RootStack navigation={{
            dispatch: props.dispatch,
            state: props.nav,
        }} 
    />
)

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    nav: state.navReducer,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SiraRoute);
```

and the index.js file is

```
const store = configureStore();

const sira = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <SiraRoute  />
  </Provider>
)

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SIRA', () => sira);
```

but am getting ***navigation.getChildNavigation is not a function*** error.

- react-navigation: ^2.0.1
- react-native: 0.55.3

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the fact that React Navigation is dropping redux support.

[React Navigation Docs:](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html)

> Warning: in the next major version of React Navigation, to be released
>   in Fall 2018, we will no longer provide any information about how to
>   integrate with Redux and it may cease to work.

Discussion about how you can migrate away from Redux in react navigation:
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4490